# The entity framework and database agnostic programming, possibilities?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, database-agnostic

We want to use the Entity Framework (.NET 4.0) to build applications that can deal with Sql Server, MySQL and Oracle. And maybe Sqlite too.

It should be easy to switch the db vendor by some setting in a config file.

Is this possible? I prefer real life examples!

What kind of providers did you use?

Answer (score 3):

[NHibernate?](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasessupportedbyNHibernate)

But in the real world these plans usually result in an application that does not use any of the strong points of any of the database.

Comment: agreed ... and they must pander to the least-common-denominator of all the databases supported, which means the customers may as well just use the cheapest DB available, which means they don't need it to be DB-agnostic after all :)

Comment: agreed... the weakest link. It's hard enough to create an app that works well with one database. I thought we left the 'it's just a data dump' attitude behind us.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. 
Take a look at our [EF Query samples](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/efquerysamples.zip)